# How to get the date from year, month, week of the month, and day of the week in php

Tags: php, date, weekday

I have the year, month, week of the month and day of the week. I want to get a date.
For example:

```php
$year = 2019;
$month = 8;
$week = 2; // second week of the month
$day = 2; // tuesday
$date = getDate($year, $month, $week, $day); // $date = '06/08/2019'
```

Comment: After many try, the `getDate()` function is actually empty and I'm out of idea on how to implement it...

Comment: in the example, 06/08/2019 is on week 2 because 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th august are on week 1

Comment: That's incorrect, the second week of August this year starts on [Sunday, August 11th, 2019](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+week+of+august+2019).

Comment: If you wanted to get the date of `06/08/2019` then the week would be `1` and the day would be `3`. If you want a solution for the correct date as mentioned then there is one, although if you are making up your own standards there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use PHP [Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Something like this

```
$date = new DateTime('first day of August 2019');
$date->modify('tuesday next week');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

It needs a little bit of conversion from numbers to strings but it's useful when you need to handle relative dates.